# Switching from componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps in React

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core

I'm following a tutorial to create a React app with a .net core backend. I'm currently trying to set up a component for editing/updating my entity. The tutorial makes use of the now deprecated componentWillReceiveProps to pull through data for the entity being updated. I'm trying to update this to getDerivedStateFromProps. I've managed to get it populating the input fields, but now I'm unable to actually edit those fields before submitting. I think it might be something to do with my if statement.

Here's the full code from my component:

```
class UpdateBusiness extends Component {
    state = {
        businessForm: {},
        prevPropsData: this.props.data,
        isFormValid: true
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setState({ businessForm: returnInputConfiguration() });
        let id = this.props.match.params.id;
        let url = '/api/business/' + id + '/account';
        this.props.onGetBusinessById(url, { ...this.props });
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        
        const updatedBusinessForm = state.businessForm;
        if (props.data !== state.prevPropsData)
        {
            updatedBusinessForm.businessName.value = props.data.businessName;
            updatedBusinessForm.businessWebsite.value = props.data.businessWebsite;
            updatedBusinessForm.contractStartDate.value = moment(props.data.contractStartDate).toDate()
            return {
                businessForm: updatedBusinessForm
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

    handleChangeEvent = (event, id) => {
        const updatedBusinessForm = { ...this.state.businessForm };
        updatedBusinessForm[id] = formUtilityActions.executeValidationAndReturnFormElement(event, updatedBusinessForm, id);

        const counter = formUtilityActions.countInvalidElements(updatedBusinessForm);

        this.setState({ businessForm: updatedBusinessForm, isFormValid: counter === 0 })
    }

    redirectToBusinessList = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/business-list');
    }

    updateBusiness = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const businessToUpdate = {
            businessName: this.state.businessForm.businessName.value,
            contractStartDate: this.state.businessForm.contractStartDate.value,
            businessWebsite: this.state.businessForm.businessWebsite.value
        }

        const url = "/api/business/" + this.props.data.businessId;

        this.props.onUpdateBusiness(url, businessToUpdate, { ...this.props });
    }

    render() {
        const formElementsArray = formUtilityActions.convertStateToArrayOfFormObjects({ ...this.state.businessForm });

        return (
            <Card>
                <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.updateBusiness}>
                    {
                        formElementsArray.map(element => {
                            return <Input key={element.id} elementType={element.config.element}
                                id={element.id} label={element.config.label}
                                type={element.config.type} value={element.config.value}
                                changed={(event) => this.handleChangeEvent(event, element.id)}
                                errorMessage={element.config.errorMessage} invalid={!element.config.valid}
                                shouldValidate={element.config.validation}
                                touched={element.config.touched}
                                blur={(event) => this.handleChangeEvent(event, element.id)} />
                        })
                    }
                    <br />
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Col mdOffset={6} md={1}>
                            <Button type='submit' bsStyle='info' disabled={!this.state.isFormValid}>Update</Button>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={1}>
                            <Button bsStyle='danger' onClick={this.redirectToBusinessList}>Cancel</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
                <SuccessModal show={this.props.showSuccessModal} modalHeaderText={'Success message'}
                    modalBodyText={'Action completed successfully'}
                    okButtonText={'OK'}
                    successClick={() => this.props.onCloseSuccessModal('/business-list', { ...this.props })} />
                <ErrorModal show={this.props.showErrorModal} modalHeaderText={'Error message'}
                    modalBodyText={this.props.errorMessage}
                    okButtonText={'OK'}
                    closeModal={() => this.props.onCloseErrorModal()} />
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.repository.data,
        showSuccessModal: state.repository.showSuccessModal,
        showErrorModal: state.errorHandler.showErrorModal,
        errorMessage: state.errorHandler.errorMessage
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onGetBusinessById: (url, props) => dispatch(repositoryActions.getData(url, props)),
        onUpdateBusiness: (url, business, props) => dispatch(repositoryActions.putData(url, business, props)),
        onCloseSuccessModal: (url, props) => dispatch(repositoryActions.closeSuccessModal(props, url)),
        onCloseErrorModal: () => dispatch(errorHandlerActions.closeErrorModal())

    }
}
```

Here's the componentWillReceiveProps code from the tutorial that was working:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        const updatedBusinessForm = { ...this.state.businessForm };
        let nameObject = { ...updatedBusinessForm.businessName };
        let websiteObject = { ...updatedBusinessForm.businessWebsite };
        let dateObject = { ...updatedBusinessForm.contractStartDate };
        nameObject.value = nextProps.data.businessName;
        nameObject.valid = true;
        dateObject.value = moment(nextProps.data.contractStartDate).toDate();
        websiteObject.value = nextProps.data.businessWebsite;
        websiteObject.valid = true;
        updatedBusinessForm['businessName'] = nameObject;
        updatedBusinessForm['contractStartDate'] = dateObject;
        updatedBusinessForm['businessWebsite'] = websiteObject;
        this.setState({ businessForm: updatedBusinessForm });
}
```

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful. I have considered using componentDidUpdate but I think as I'm updating the state, this would be the wrong hook to use?

Comment: you are starting the project or is it legacy code?

Comment: You're returning `null` if props and state are equal - that should probably be `return state` (i.e. you don't want the state to change).

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I'm not sure what you mean by your question, but I am using a tutorial to start my own project.

Comment: @gerrod I've tried that but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference. The issue I'm hitting is that the code in my getDerivedStateFromProps won't let me update the input fields. It sets the value of each input field to the corresponding value pulled from the database, which is good, but it then won't allow me to edit those values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDerivedStateFromProps` method is overwriting your form values on every render. You're not updating the `prevPropsData` property when you update the form - you'd have to change the return to -

```
return {
    businessForm: updatedBusinessForm,
    prevPropsData: props.data,
};
```

But overall - creating state from props is a bit of an anti-pattern because it's hard to get right (for exactly the types of reasons you're running in to here). A better alternative would be to not keep local state on the form, and instead promote the state to the parent control which is supplying the props in the first place. This is the best option because it means the form's state is only stored in one place (the parent control). [Here's a small demo using functional components](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hvxqpl?file=Form.tsx):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const FormControls = (props) => {
  const handleFieldChange = fieldName => event =>
    props.onFormValueChange(fieldName, event.target.value);

  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" 
          value={props.values.name}
          onChange={handleFieldChange('name')} 
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" id="age"
          value={props.values.age}
          onChange={handleFieldChange('age')}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

const FormHost = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: '',
    age: 0,
  });

  const handleFormValueChange = (fieldName, nextValue) => {
    setForm(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [fieldName]: nextValue,
    }));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <FormControls
        values={form}
        onFormValueChange={handleFormValueChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```